# Disabling of second dropdown depending on the value of the first dropdown in JSF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf

I have dropdown with id "onemenu1". For the jquery given below the onchange event is not working. I am unable to know the problem. Any leads will be appreciated.

```js
$('#oneMenu1').change(function() {
  if ($('#oneMenu1').val() == 'Never') {
    $('#secsDropdown').attr('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p:selectOneMenu id="oneMenu1" required="true" styleClass="vehAvailClass" requiredMessage="#{itrams['RefreshRateReq']}" editable="true" style="width:100px" value="#{dashboardAction.selectRefreshRate}">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{dashboardAction.vehicleAvail}" itemValue="#{dashboardAction.vehicleAvail}" />
  <f:selectItems value="#{dashboardAction.getRRList()}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<!-- JIRA 741 start  -->

<p:selectOneMenu id="secsDropdown" required="true" value="#{dashboardAction.unitOfRefreshRate}" style="width:70px">
  <f:selectItems value="#{dashboardAction.getRRUnitList()}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: can you inspect your element for generated id for select?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.prop()` method for it and better to go with class instead:

```
$('.vehAvailClass').change(function() {
    $(this).next('select').prop('disabled', this.value === 'Never'); 
});                                      // this.value === 'Never'
                                         // results in true/false
```

---

If you have your `select` elements in `form` the you have to notice the id has been changed in this manner `formid:selectid`. So, in your case it might be something like `yourformID:oneMenu1`.

---

Updates:

```
$('#dashboardFormId\\:oneMenu1').change(function() {
    $('#dashboardFormId\\:secsDropdown').prop('disabled', this.value === 'Never'); 
});
```

Here you have to escape the `:`.

Comment: `var output = $('#dashboardFormId:oneMenu1').val();` This is not giving anything and `var output = $('#oneMenu1').val();` is undefined

Comment: `if (($( "#dashboardFormId\\:oneMenu1 option:selected" ).text() == 'Never') || ($( "#dashboardFormId\\:oneMenu1 option:selected" ).text() == 'Default')) {
          $('#dashboardFormId\\:secsDropdown').attr('disabled', true);
      } ` The control is going inside the if condition if i select "never"/"default", but the disabled attribute is not being set to true. I tried using prop also.